# Evento de click de um botão

Tags: android

Considere o seguinte *layout* de uma *Activity*:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickNoBotao"
        android:text="Login"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Alterativa I:**

```
Button mBotao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateAccess);

mBotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Código aqui
    }
});
```

**Alterativa II:**

```
public void clickNoBotao () {

        //Código aqui

}
```

**Alterativa III:**

```
public void clickNoBotao (View view) {

        //Código aqui

}
```

**Alterativa IV:**

```
Button mBotao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateAccess);

mBotao.setOnClick(new View.OnClick() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Código aqui
    }
});
```

Eu gostaria de saber se essas alternativas e os código de evento estão de acordo com o código *LinearLayout*

Answer (score 2):

Das alternativas apresentadas apenas a **I** e **III** são válidas.

A classe [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) usa uma implementação da interface [View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) para informar que o botão foi clicado.

Essa implementação deve ser associada ao botão através do método `setOnClickListener()`.

O SDK disponibiliza a possibilidade de o método `onClick()` da interface possa ser indicado no *xml*, através do atributo `android:onClick`, e implementado na Activity.

O método a implementar tem de ter a mesma assinatura do método da interface: `public void onClick(View view)`.
É por isso que a alternativa **II** não é válida.
O nome pode ser outro, desde que igual ao indicado no xml.

A alternativa **IV** também não é valida, desde logo, porque a classe Button não tem nenhum método chamado `setOnClick()`.

Relacionado: [Vantagem e desavantagem entre onClick e setOnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button).

Comment: Desde já eu agradeço pela resposta , e estou aprendendo agora essa área de android , pois sou programador de php e c#, obrigado, e irei estudar esse tema,.